# Why indexes are going to unusable status while droping partition even though update index appended the statement

Tags: oracle

if we create global indexes and used the below statement ALTER TABLE t1 DROP PARTITION p5 UPDATE GLOBAL INDEXES; then indexes are going to unusable status

may i know the reason

Comment: Is your table `index-organized`?. If not then use `UPDATE INDEXES` instead of `UPDATE GLOBAL INDEXES` and check.

Answer (score 0):

You must be doing something else. That statement will not make global indexes unusable. Either the global indexes were unusable before this statement ran already or you are running something else afterwards.

[DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=3bf8943d3ce0909359933d1e56b224e1) to demonstrate that this syntax is correct.